# Skip some specific records in activeadmin index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to display Patient's unique enrollment numbers of only those patients who enrolled on `donation` on index page.

I have `on_donation` field in patients table.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Patient, as: 'Patient' do
  belongs_to :physician

  actions :index
  menu false

  index do
    column :patient_uen do |row|
      link_to(row.patient.uen, '#') if row.patient&.on_donation?
    end
  end
end
```

But this is showing empty lines for the patients who are not admitted on donation.

Is there a way to place the `if-condition` or something like that in *index do* so that it would not show the empty lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following `controller` to your `ActiveAdmin` class before `index` method

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    super.where(on_donation: true)
  end
end
```